# Sage refuses to open any Jupyter notebook even though Anaconda is installed

Tags: math, jupyter-notebook, sage

I have installed Sage using the latest installer and I can open a Sage terminal (by clicking on it from the start menu...not by entering 'sage' in Windows command line).

I have then installed Anaconda. I can enter 'python' in Windows command line and it works. But the puzzling part is jupyter notebooks. By my understanding, it comes with Anaconda so, I should be able to open my Sage console and type some version of 'n jupyter' or 'njupyter' or '-n jupyter' etc to get a sage Jupyter notebook running.

This is NOT happening at all. Instead I get

[image]

Edit: I would like to get Sage to open a Jupyter notebook on my computer but the commands I tried (in the screenshot provided) just keep failing. I got a version of these commands from the Sage tutorial itself and still, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to get this working are much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @FabioPetrillo I would like to get Sage to open a Jupyter notebook on my computer but the commands I tried (in the screenshot provided) just keep failing. I got a version of these commands from the Sage tutorial itself and still, it doesn't work. Pointers on what I am doing wrong would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The Sage-Windows installer installs three shortcuts for you:

- "SageMath x.y" -- to use SageMath in the (Cygwin) command line
- "SageMath x.y Notebook" -- to use SageMath in Jupyter
- "SageMath x.y shell" -- to access a Cygwin terminal where Sage has not been started

Have you tried using the "SageMath 9.3 Notebook" shortcut?

See a guide at

- https://wiki.sagemath.org/SageWindows